# Image in final project is displaying a second overlapping image

Tags: html, css, image, overlapping

So to start, my project is due by Tuesday, so I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

I created a website for my final project, that when the page is inspected, displays everything properly.  However once I upload the page to the school server and inspect it there, it displays things differently.  I'm including screen shots of what I am seeing with this.
[What I initially see...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EGgT.jpg)

[What I see after uploading to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQkBI.jpg)

HTML for the section of the page that has the image is in is below:

```css
header { background-position: left;
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: 20%;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         font-family: Georgia, Serif;
         height: 160px;
     }

#wrapper { background-color: #8b4513;
        margin-right: auto;
           margin-left: auto;
        width: 80%;
           min-width: 720px;
           max-width: 1280px;
           box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
  }

.logo { background-color: #FFFFFF;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 160px;
        padding: 1em
         }

h1 { color: #000000; 
     display: inline-block;
     line-height: 200%;
     height: 72px;
     margin-bottom: 1.5em;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-indent: 10%;
     text-decoration: none;
     }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <header>
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="../project/images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        <h1>Portland Historical Tours</h1>
        </a>
        </header>
```

Any help would be very appreciated, though please keep in mind that I'm new to this and the HTML/css I'm using is not anything advanced (such as including java script).

Comment: you're missing a `;` in `.logo` after `padding: 1em`. I'm assuming that isn't the problem though. Not sure why the image would be appearing twice, that's really weird.

Comment: @MichaelCoker it is the last property in the rule. It does not require a `;`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli today i learned! Thanks.

Comment: From the code you posted, it should not occur. You should post the whole page as it gets rendered and the CSS.

Comment: maybe caching problems? Try a hard refresh

Comment: I did add the ";" that was missing and reuploaded to the server, but I'm still getting the same issue.

I'll try a hard refresh next and see what that does.

Comment: I did try the hard refresh and that fixed it.  I never knew about that as a method of refreshing the page.  But it was certainly odd that the page was doing that to begin with.

Thanks for the help.